# pynacl library needed in order to use voice

Tags: discord, bots, discord.py

I wanted to add a voice module to my discord bot, but I always get an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HAyG.png), so I did a little research and found a stackoverflow answer from Patrick Haugh. [This is the the answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DgU5.png) . Unfortunately, this didn't help me because I already installed this module

Comment: uninstall & reinstall pynacl

Comment: I've already tried

Comment: Have you tried installing `PyNaCl` by typing `pip install pynacl` ?

Comment: Yes i did that.

Comment: You aren't running your bot in a venv by any chance?